# Getting Duplicate links in Scraping

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to collect "a" tags which are in  class="featured" from a site http://www.pakistanfashionmagazine.com 
I wrote this piece of code it has no error but it duplicates the links. How can I overcome this duplication ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

results= soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":'featured'})

for div in results:
    links = div.findAll('a')
for a in links:
    print "http://www.pakistanfashionmagazine.com/" +a['href']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual HTML page* has two links *per item `<div>`*; one for the image, the other for the `<h4>` tag:

```html
<div class="item">

    <div class="image">
        <a href="/dress/casual-dresses/bella-embroidered-lawn-collection-3-stitched-suits-pkr-14000-only.html" title="BELLA Embroidered Lawn Collection*3 STITCHED SUITS@PKR 14000 ONLY"><img src="/siteimages/upload/BELLA-Embroidered-Lawn-Collection3-STITCHED-SUITSPKR-14000-ONLY_1529IM1-thumb.jpg" alt="Featured Product" /></a>                    </div>

  <div class="detail">
        <h4><a href="/dress/casual-dresses/bella-embroidered-lawn-collection-3-stitched-suits-pkr-14000-only.html">BELLA Embroidered Lawn Collection*3 STITCHED SUITS@PKR 14000 ONLY</a></h4>
                                <em>updated: 2013-06-03</em>
        <p>BELLA Embroidered Lawn Collection*3 STITCHED SUITS@PKR 14000 ONLY</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Limit your links to just one or the other; I'd use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here:

```
links = soup.select('div.featured .detail a[href]')
for link in links:
    print "http://www.pakistanfashionmagazine.com/" + link['href']
```

Now 32 links are printed, not 64.

If you needed to limit this to just the second `featured` section (*Beauty Tips*), then do so; select the `featured` divs, pick the second from the list, then

```
links = soup.select('div.featured')[1].select('.detail a[href]')
```

Now you have just the 8 links in that section.

Comment: The code I wrote is to print just 8 links and it do so but each link appears twice. The reason you gave is absolutely right. But the edits you suggested are giving unnecessary links @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user3834883: then *narrow it down further*. The page you link to produces 64 links when I load it and run your code (adjusted for indentation).

Comment: @user3834883: There are 64 `<a>` links under the `featured` div, 32 unique links.

Comment: @user3834883: if you only wanted the 8 links under the 'Beautity Tips' headers, you need to narrow down your link search to just that section.

Comment: yeah I was wanting to get those 8 likes under Beauty Tips header @Martijn Pieters

Comment: one more thing if I want to scrap the links of "Latest Fashion Events" tab of the site what I would have to do for that ? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user3834883: Find a way to filter just that section. I've given you to more tools to do so now, I'm sure you can manage it. :-)

Comment: @user3834883: there is a `upcoming` class on the surrounding div, going from there gives: `soup.select('.upcoming .detail a')`.

Comment: Awesome Man, Kindly tell me how so quickly are you finding the desired class :) I am extremely new to Python and web development.       @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user3834883: I used the developer tools in my browser to inspect the elements.